# How can I get a PEM Base 64 from a pfx in Java?

Tags: java, base64, pkcs#12

I'm using a webservice that requires a  PKCS12 Base64 certificate (a String), I have a pfx file but I suppose I need to convert to a PEM using base 64.

I can do this with this bash command:

```
openssl base64 -in pfx.pfx -out pem.pem
```

But I need to do this in java.

I have this method to load a *.cer file and then use Base64.encode to get a string , but I get an exception

```
public X509Certificate getX509Certificate(final File certificateFile) throws CertificateException,
        IOException {
    try {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(certificateFile);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        return (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        throw e;
    }

}
```

And this is the exception I get:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: signed fields invalid    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1768)     at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:196)     at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:97)     at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)   at fel.CFDIUtils.getX509Certificate(CFDIUtils.java:55)  at fel.CFDIUtils.getPfxBase64(CFDIUtils.java:82)    at cfdipruebas.Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pfx file is not a certificate, but a keystore. To convert it to a pem certificate without resorting to openssl, you could do the following:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("<path_to_pfx_file>");
java.security.KeyStore ks = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(fis,"pfx_password".toCharArray());
Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate("certificate_alias");

BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();        
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("<path_to_generated_pem_file>");
fos.write(X509Factory.BEGIN_CERT.getBytes());
encoder.encodeBuffer(cert.getEncoded(), fos);
fos.write(X509Factory.END_CERT.getBytes());

fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

If, instead, you simply want to convert the pfx file to base64, like you did using openssl in your question, do the following:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("<path_to_pfx_file>");
ByteArrayOutputStream outBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] InBuffer = new byte[512];
int read = 0;
while ( (read = fis.read(InBuffer)) != -1 ) {
   outBuffer.write(InBuffer, 0, read);
}

BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
File fout = new File("<path_to_base64_pfx_file>");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);

encoder.encodeBuffer(outBuffer.toByteArray(), fos);

fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

And if you want a string instead of writing the result to a file:

```
String myPfxEncodedAsBase64 = encoder.encodeBuffer(outBuffer.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Wow excelent, I'm getting now a pem certificate , but if I run the bash command (in the question) I get a plain text document with a bunch of characters, with this method I get a certificate.. The webservice is asking for  "PKCS12 Certificate in Base64"  (a String) .. Thanks :)

Comment: Simply converting the pfx to base64 should do the trick. See edited answer above.